# Pass CheckButton's number using Python Class

Tags: python

I created a class in order to create a batch of checkbuttons as follows.
I'm trying  to get the chekbutton's number to indicate which one was pressed( with no success ).

stat functio, when called, sends status of all checkbuttons.

any ideas ?

```
class dev_buttons2(object):
  def __init__(self,master,buts_list):
    self.status=[]
    for i in range(len(buts_list)):
        self.var = IntVar()
        self.name=buts_list[i]
        self.c = Checkbutton(master,text=buts_list[i], variable=self.var,
        indicatoron=0,command=self.cb,width=10,height=2)
        self.c.grid(column=i, padx=5,row = 10)
        self.status.append(self.var)

def cb(self):
    print(self.name)


def stat():
    return self.status
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Lambda function - I passed as much values as I want to `arg` ( see comment at code ).

```
class SwitchButtons:
def __init__(self, master, frame, num_of_buttons):
    self.master = master
    self.status = []
    self.buts = []
    self.leds = []
    bg_window = "DeepSkyBlue4"
    self.framein = Frame(frame)
    self.framein.grid(padx=5, pady=5)

    #Create Widgets of buttons
    for i in range(num_of_buttons):
        button_var = StringVar()
        entry_var = IntVar()
        led_var = StringVar()
        t = 35
        ent = Entry(self.framein, textvariable=entry_var, width=4, justify="center")
        ent.grid(column=i, row=2, sticky=W, padx=t)

        led = Label(self.framein, textvariable=led_var, width=4, bg="red", fg="white", relief="ridge")
        led_var.set("off")
        led.grid(row=0, column=i, pady=0)

        c = Checkbutton(self.framein, text="Switch " + str(i), variable=button_var, indicatoron=0,
                        width=10, height=2, onvalue="on", offvalue="off",
                        command=lambda arg=[i, button_var, entry_var]: #### Use Lambda to pass several arguments to "arg"
 self.cb(arg))
        c.grid(column=i, padx=30, pady=5, row=1)
        button_var.set("off")

        mins = Label(self.framein, text="min.", width=4, justify="center", fg="black")
        mins.grid(column=i, row=2, sticky=E, padx=t)

        self.status.append([button_var, led_var, entry_var])
        self.buts.append(c)
        self.leds.append(led)
        ###

def cb(self, but, state='', a=''):
    # but = [ switch#, switch state, delay] ## explanatory

    ##In use only in CB_DELAYED
    if state != '':
        but[1].set(state)

    def switch_onoff():
        if but[1].get() == "on":
            self.leds[but[0]].config(bg="green")
            self.status[but[0]][1].set("on")
        elif but[1].get() == "off":
            self.leds[but[0]].config(bg="red")
            self.status[but[0]][1].set("off")

    if but[2].get() > 0 and but[1].get() == "on":
        a = ", Auto shutdown in %s minutes." % (but[2].get())
        switch_onoff()
        print("Delayed", but[1].get())
        self.cb_delayed(but)
    else:
        switch_onoff()

    self.master.loop.device_chage_state(but[0], but[1].get(), text=a)

def cb_delayed(self, but):
    self.framein.after(but[2].get() * 1000, self.cb, but, "off")
```